# MySQL Data Import with secure_file_priv issue

Tags: mysql, centos

I've got a newbie question about MySQL data import.

I am trying to import a .csv file into my MySQL database, then i have the "secure_file_priv" error, it spends me whole day to google and try, i found that the value for secure_file_priv is '/var/lib/mysql-files', as i am using a Centos 8. I placed the csv file into the directory, but it keeps showing the same error.

my code:

```
mysql> show variables like "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                 |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| secure_file_priv | /var/lib/mysql-files/ |
+------------------+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> load data infile '/var/lib/mysql-files/master.clientlist.csv'
-> into table agentcompany_compare
-> fields terminated by ','
-> lines terminated by '\n'
-> ignore 1 rows;
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv 
option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Comment: Setting says "files", your code says "file"

Comment: `/var/lib/mysql-files/` not equal `\var\lib\mysql-file\` slash vs back-slash

Comment: 'var/lib/mysql-files/master.clientlist.csv' #thank you so much to point out the syntax, but it still doesnt work.. same error

Comment: I've tested it with outfile and it works perfectly, however not with infile, read every articles in google still no clue..

Comment: ok seems i moved on now, now it says i dont have a correct integer value, i will keep update if i solved it.

Answer (score 0):

New Progress:

I have no clue but it "works", yet no data is correctly write into mysql, please see my codes:

```
mysql>  load data infile '/var/lib/mysql- 
files/clientlist.csv' into table agentcompany_compare
-> fields terminated by ','
-> lines terminated by ';\n'
-> ignore 1 rows;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0
```

i've tried a lot, for your kind reference:

```
mysql> load data infile '/var/lib/mysql- 
files/clientlist.csv' into table agentcompany_compare
-> fields terminated by ','
-> lines terminated by ';\n';
ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 
'idagentcompany   acid   acname   actel   acaddress       
logo
1       1       "
'

mysql> load data infile '/var/lib/mysql- 
files/clientlist.csv' into table agentcompany_compare
-> fields terminated by ','
-> lines terminated by '\r\n';
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: 
'idagentcompany    acid    acname actel    acaddress       
logo' for column 'idagentcompany' at row 1
```

Tough problem.